# Can I run multiple instances of a Socket.IO node app on the same machine without changing the socket.IO port for each instance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Lets say I build a node app called Program_v0.0.1 running Socket.io on port 4545.

```
var socket = require('socket.io')(4545);
```

With PM2 (It allows one to run multiple instances, keeps them running, etc), I run Program_v0.0.1 I want to also run an instance of Program_v0.0.2. **Do I need to change the port that Program_v0.0.2 runs Socket.io on?**

```
var socket = require('socket.io')(4546);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance you would have reserved the port `4545`. If you want to run another instance, use another port.

In short, yes you will have to change the port for 2nd instance.